# Convert dataframe column names to cell values of a new variable

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below

```
d<-structure(list(WaterYear = c(2014, 2015), Discharge = c(1783.939638, 
1970.891674), EnvWater = c(6, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and I want to convert it in a way that will have 3 columns. The `WaterYear` as it is, the `Category` which will include `Discharge` and `EnvWater` and the `Value` with thei relative values. Normally I want to apply it to more than 2 columns.

Comment: You may need to reshape to long i.e. `library(tidyr); d %>% pivot_longer(cols = -WaterYear, names_to = 'Category', values_to = 'Value')`

Comment: that did it indeed thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reshape to 'long' with `pivot_longer` to create the required data

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(d, cols = -WaterYear, names_to = 'Category', values_to = 'Value')
```